# Can I multiply the numbers from a text file?

Tags: text, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have a text file that looks like this
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
Is there a way that I can multiply all these numbers together as is? Or will I have to move them all onto separate lines? I know the basics of BufferedReader and Scanner but I'm not sure if this is possible. What I'm trying to do is multiply a list of prime numbers that I downloaded from online. Here's what I have now (updated)

```
import java.io.*;    
public class BufferReader {   
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String delete = "[ ]+";
   BufferedReader br = null;

   try{ 
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));     

       System.out.println("Reading the file using readLine() method:");
   String contentLine = br.readLine();
   while (contentLine != null) {
      System.out.println(contentLine);
      contentLine = br.readLine();
      String show [] = contentLine.split(delete);
   }



   } 
   catch (IOException ioe) 
   {
   ioe.printStackTrace();
   } 
   finally 
   {
   try {
      if (br != null)
     br.close();

   } 
   catch (IOException ioe) 
       {
    System.out.println("Error in closing the BufferedReader");
   }
}
 }
}
```

Comment: Of course you can... Read each line then parse each line according to your logic e.g. split the strings based on the whitespace then convert each resulting string to integer and do their product.

Comment: Ok, sorry if that was a dumb question but file reading is just really confusing for me

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I'm just totally lost

Comment: So what happens when you run that code?  e.g. Does it run or throw an error? If so what error and on what line?  If it runs, what is the output vs expected output?

Comment: I get this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at BufferReader.main(BufferReader.java:19)
And I'd like each of the numbers to be recognized as separate so I can multiply them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class NumberReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 1. Determine the input location
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:/temp/file.txt");

        // 2. Read the contents of the file into a single string
        byte[] contentBytes = new byte[255];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while (fis.read(contentBytes)!=-1){
            bos.write(contentBytes);
        }
        fis.close();
        String contents = bos.toString();
        System.out.println(contents);

        // 3. Parse the string and split according to the system's endline
        String[] lines = contents.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        int product = 1;
        for (String line : lines){
            String[] numbers = line.trim().split(" ");
            for (String number : numbers){
                System.out.println("number read: "+number);
                Integer convertedNumber = Integer.parseInt(number.trim());
                product = product * convertedNumber;
                System.out.println("new product: "+product);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I ran the code on your input and got:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
number read: 1
new product: 1
number read: 2
new product: 2
number read: 3
new product: 6
number read: 4
new product: 24
number read: 5
new product: 120
number read: 6
new product: 720
number read: 7
new product: 5040
number read: 8
new product: 40320
```

Comment: This is just something I noticed but the method you provided works very quickly, could I use it to replace a scanner/bufferedReader to read a large number from a text file? Or would it not actually be any faster?